# Binary logic emulator logic error

Tags: c++, boolean, logic

If you need any more information just ask.

What I'm trying to do is emulate boolean logic that could be found on a computer in C++ code. Right now I'm trying to create a 32 bit adder. When I run the testing code, I get an output of 32, which is wrong it should be 64. I'm fairly sure that my `add` function is correct. The code for those gates is:

```
bool and(bool a, bool b)
{
return nand(nand(a,b),nand(a,b));
}

bool or(bool a, bool b)
{
return nand(nand(a,a),nand(b,b));
}

bool nor(bool a, bool b)
{
return nand(nand(nand(a,a), nand(b,b)),nand(nand(a,a), nand(b,b)));
}
```

The code for the add function:

```
bool *add(bool a, bool b, bool carry)
{
static bool out[2];

out[0] = nor(nor(a, b), carry);
out[1] = or(and(b,carry),and(a,b));

return out;
}

bool *add32(bool a[32], bool b[32], bool carry)
{
static bool out[33];
bool *tout;

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    tout = add(a[i], b[i], (i==0)?false:tout[1]);
    out[i] = tout[0];
}
out[32] = tout[1];

return out;
}
```

The code I'm using to test this is:

```
bool *a = int32tobinary(32);
bool *b = int32tobinary(32);
bool *c = add32(a, b, false);
__int32 i = binarytoint32(c);
```

Those two functions are:

```
bool *int32tobinary(__int32 a)
{
static bool _out[32];
bool *out = _out;
int i;

for(i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
{
    out[i] = (a&1) ? true : false;
    a >>= 1;
}

return out;
}

__int32 binarytoint32(bool b[32])
{
int result = 0;
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    if(b[i] == true)
        result += (int)pow(2.0f, 32 - i - 1);
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? something like step by step / printf debugging to see at what point it deviates from what you expect maybe?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a debugger. In any case, returning a pointer to a static variable is usually a bad idea.

Comment: `or` and `and` are reserved words in C++, you cannot use them as identifiers. A decent compiler would complain about this. I’m inferring that you’re probably using MSVC or an old compiler.

Comment: I think add32 needs to add from right to left, i.e. `i` should start at the LS bit, which seems to be bit 31 in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Where to start?

As noted in the comments, returning a pointer to a static variable is wrong.

This

```
out[0] = nor(nor(a, b), carry);
```

should be

```
out[0] = xor(xor(a, b), carry);
```

This `out[1] = or(and(b,carry),and(a,b));` is also incorrect. `out[1]` must be `true`, when `a == true` and `carry == true`.

`add32` assumes index 0 to be the LSB, `int32tobinary` and `int32tobinary` assume index 0 to be MSB.

Comment: Also the carry out bit is at the wrong end of tout, I think ?

Comment: In add I changed the out[1] = line to be: `out[1] = or(and(xor(a,b),carry),and(a,b));` which I think is right according to the diagram here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics) "full adder logic diagram"